# Load JSON in gist into table using query

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to load a series of json results on GitHub into a table. The gist can be found [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheMightyLlama/9f4f1b4c2c078a6080c9212aba6beb59/raw/092fc02afcbd11ea26e7a08541b8dfae4748218a/News%2520Summary%2520Sample). I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814493/how-to-load-json-data-into-bootstrap-table) which helps with the population of the table. However, I'm having trouble retrieving the data from the gist.

I've modified the data section of the question as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $table = $('#table');
    $.getJSON('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheMightyLlama/9f4f1b4c2c078a6080c9212aba6beb59/raw/092fc02afcbd11ea26e7a08541b8dfae4748218a/News%2520Summary%2520Sample', function(mydata) {
  });

  $(function () {
      $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata
      });
  });
</script>
```

And the table as below:

```
<div class="container">
  <table id="table" data-height="460">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="title">Title</th>
        <th data-field="date">Date</th>
        <th data-field="category">Category</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `mydata` you used in `getJSON` function is local variable and that was just created at    the time when that function called and can only usable within that function. Write the load table code inside `getJSON`
[Here is JSFiddle Working Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qdpg65v9/)

```
var $table = $('#table');
$.getJSON('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheMightyLlama/9f4f1b4c2c078a6080c9212aba6beb59/raw/092fc02afcbd11ea26e7a08541b8dfae4748218a/News%2520Summary%2520Sample', function(mydata) {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata
    });
});
```

Comment: @sSubhan Khalid is there a way to remove the table headers?

Comment: what you need instead of table headers?

Comment: Nothing. I'm attempting to make a list of the data in the gist as part of a bootstrap `list-group` container. Perhaps that's for another question...

Comment: umm yes, it's different thing from it. create new thread for it.